# How to patch ftplib.FTP in a Python testcase with fake login credentials?

Tags: python, testing, patch, testcase

There is a python module which follows as x.y.z in which a function is present :-

```
from ftplib import FTP

def connect(host,user,pass) :
    ftp = FTP(host, user, pass)
```

Test case is follows :-

```
classs testClass(unittest.TestCase)

@patch(x.y.z.FTP)
def test_connect(self,MOCKFTP) :
    mock_ftp_obj = MOCKFTP()
    connect('fakehost','fakeuser','fakepass')
```

Running the test case gives - 530 login incorrect !

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is incorrect path value `x.y.z.FTP` FTP is actually present in ftplib package.

Following works as expected:

**x.y.z.py:**

```
import ftplib


def connect(host, user, pass1):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host=host, user=user, passwd=pass1)
```

**testz.py:**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from x.y.z import connect


class testClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('ftplib.FTP', autospec=True)
    def test_download_file(self, mock_ftp):
        connect('fakehost','fakeuser','fakepass')
        mock_ftp.assert_called_with('fakehost','fakeuser','fakepass')
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But I do not follow. When FTP is imported as in from ftlib import FTP in x.y.z.py isn't the FTP class within that file and it is being mocked ?

Comment: Oh no, FTP is a class that is present in ftlib package, even if you import that in another module. So you have to do as mentioned in the answer.  If it works and helps you could you please accept the answer?